# Преобразование ломаной линии

Tags: c++, алгоритм, геометрия, 2d

Я имею неравномерную сетку в виде координат узлов в двумерном пространстве
Узлы сетки хранятся в одномерном векторе, где нумерация снизу-вверх слева-направо

[image: сетка]

Также мне дана ломаная **монотонная** линия (обозначена синим цветом на рисунке), из которой необходимо получить ломаную линию, проходящую через узлы сетки (обозначено красной линией на рисунке).

Количество точек ломаной линии не совпадает с количеством точек результирующей ломаной.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи по решению данной задачи?

Comment: Для каждой точки синей линии найти ближайший узел сетки и соединить. Если получившиеся соседние точки не лежат на одной прямой - соединить ступенькой.

Comment: "Я имею ***неравномерную*** сетку" - точно неравномерную? а то картинка-пример в вопросе почти везде равномерная ..

Comment: @Kromster, хм, ну вот последний столбец ячеек в сетке имеет меньший размер, чем соседние, разве такая сетка равномерная?

Comment: Возможно вам стоит определить какие квадрты пересекает синяя линия и определить для каждого квадрата отдельно, какие стороны должны быть покрашены в красный цвет. Там по сути не так много вариантов: либо одна сторона, либо уголок, либо в виде буквы П.

Comment: Получаете список всех клеток, через которые проходит ломанная линия. Получаете список всех узловых точек клеток из этого списка. Для каждой узловой точки отмечаете наличие линии в "центрированной" клетке (т.е. с габаритом 1/2 от исходящего из центра ребра с каждой стороны). Соединяете все отмеченные узловые точки. Для концевых точек может понадобиться доп шаг.

Comment: На самом деле, у вас может быть достаточно много граничных ситуаций, когда, например, синяя линия делает петлю, или зигзаг в рамках одной клетки и вам придется решать, как это "округлить". Так что пробуйте разные варианты и уточняйте "правила" в зависимости от ваших входных данных.

Comment: по моему для кривой должны быть заданы точки начала и конца

Comment: @Kromster, добавила дополнительное условие в вопрос - ломаная монотонна

Comment: у вас есть точки на кривой, или у вас есть функция?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ломаная в виде списка точек

Comment: ок, теперь все ясно. Если все еще нужно, я подумаю над решением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) Учащаем точки ломаной: в цикле определяем расстояние между соседними точками (D) у ломаной, если это расстояние больше, чем расстояние диагонали ячейки сетки (d), то вставляем дополнительною точку.

[image: исходная ломаная]
[image: измененная ломаная]

Это шаг предобработки ломаной. В конце объясню зачем это нужно

1) Определяем ближайший узел (curr_node) к начальной точке (p) исходной ломаной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в цикле:

2) Определяем соседние узлы для curr_node (соседями не считать предыдущий посещенный узел)

[image: соседи]

3) Определяем расстояние от curr_node и от его соседних узлов до следующей точки ломаной (p_next).

[image: кратчайшее расстояние]

4) Если расстояние от curr_node до p_next меньше, чем минимальное расстояние от его соседей до p_next, то p_next станет следующей точкой ломаной, иначе "посещаю" следующий узел сетки (тот соседний узел, который ближе всего к точке p_next)

Далее возвращаемся к шагу 2

В итоге получаем такую картину посещения узлов

[image: посещение узлов]

т.е. собирая посещенные узлы (черные), получаем такую ломаную, проходящую по узлам сетки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь покажу зачем нужно было делать нулевой шаг:
[image: без нулевого шага]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из этих двух рисунков, первый вариант неверный. Вставкой дополнительных точек, добьемся правильного результата

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм:

1. Выбираем клетки, через которые проходит ломаная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Циклично проверяем выбранные клетки:

2.1 Берем на границах клетки две точки, в которых ломаная пересекает эту клетку (или одну из крайних точек ломаной) и соединяем отрезком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.2 Сдвигаем отрезок так, чтоб обе точки находились на границах клетки (в случае с крайними точками ломаной).

2.3 Считаем углы между отрезком и границами к летки, к которым прилегает отрезок (достаточно неточного расчета в три варианта >45|=45|<45).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.4 "основная" граница будет та, у которой угол <45 (обведено красным). Если угол =45, то обе границы равнозначны.

Повторяем для всех клеток

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. На основе полученных выборок по две границы строим ломаную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может получиться, что ломаная пройдет "вдоль" нескольких клеток, в этом случаем сравниваем результаты проверки текущей клетки и предыдущей. Если сторона клетки с минимальным углом одинаковая в обоих клетках, то вторую сторону не учитываем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хорошо, но  думаю долго написать такую программу

Comment: Забыл еще один момент. На последней картинке в клетке В2 линия пересекает противоположные стороны клетки. В таких случая отрезки нужно проецировать на ближнюю сторону клетки, если же отрезок центрируется относительно клетки, то в этом случае выбираются противоположные стороны, а не смежные (на картинке в клетке В2 это низ и верх). К сожалению в си я не силен, но на паскале алгоритм могу набросать. Сложного ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

Проведите дополнительные воображаемые вертикальные и горизонтальные линии посередине каждого столбца и строки. У вас получится вдвое более плотная сетка. Каждый узел исходной сетки окажется заключен в ячейку новой сетки.

Если синяя линия проходит через этот прямоугольник, значит, она задействует соответствующий узел основной сетки.

Каждый сегмент синей линии пересекается с одним или более полученных прямоугольников. Зная это, можно написать функцию, возвращающую по каждому сегменту массив узлов основной сетки, связанных с этими прямоугольниками.

Обходя все сегменты синей линии мы получаем несколько таких массивов. Нужно их слить в один. Если последний узел в предыдущем массиве равен первому узлу в последующем массиве, записывать этот узел в результирующий массив всего один раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;


int main()
{  
    // вообше то с такими задачами хранить лучше в std::valarray
    // допустим количество узловых точек = 4 * 4 и для примера приведу 
    //конкретные цифры
    // в задаче же уже заданы эти цифры, я лишь для демонстрации идеи
    const int n = 4;
    valarray< int > matrix(n * n);
    // инициализируем первую строку снизу от нулевого индекса `n` штук
    valarray<int> row{ 2, 4, 7, 8 };
    // теперь учитываем что разница между соответствующим элементами
    // следующей строки должны быть одинаковыми.
    //  и допустим эти цифры заданы в векторе
    vector<int> dif{ 3, 2, 4 };
    // инициализируем последовательность по срезам
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        matrix[slice(i * n, n, 1)] = row;
        if (i == n - 1) break;
        row += dif[i];
    }
   // точки на кривой лучше хранить в map, так как кривая монотонно растет
    map<double, double> curve{{ 3.4, 2.7 }, {4.1, 6}, {5, 9.3}};
    // для первой точки на кривой
    auto para = curve.begin();
    // теперь берем  ближайшие целые этих точек
    int x = lround(para->first), y = lround(para->second);
    //...
    return 0;}
```

теперь чтобы знать к каким элементам нашей последовательности ближе точка с 
    координатами `(x, y)` всего лишь дело техники... для сравнения `y` наверняка понадобится `dif`, а
    `STL` альгоритмы дадут нам возможность рассмотреть любое количество точек
    с соответствующими предикатами. Вообшем идея такая, дальше подумайте сами